# Resolving ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."] in Django 1.9.2?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, date, datetime

Earlier I created two fields & migrated everything. after that I tried to add three fields `title`,`about`,`birthdate` into the model.
I created a model like this :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class APP1Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    percentage = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Title')
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True,default='About Yourself')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

But when I try to migrate in python shell, it is showing a validation error like this:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, app1, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying app1.0005_auto_20160217_1346...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 221, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 103, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1301, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1296, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1273, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

How to rectify this? I tried all solution i read here but it doesn't work?

I am using Django: 1.9.2

My migration File

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
```

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('app1', '0004_auto_20160217_0427'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='app1model',
        name='about',
        field=models.TextField(default='About Yourself', max_length=100, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='app1model',
        name='birth_date',
        field=models.DateField(blank=True, default='', null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='app1model',
        name='title',
        field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=100),
    ),
]
```

Comment: post the full traceback.

Comment: Please, attach the invalid migration file.

Comment: migration file??? Its the model right?? I have provided code above?

Comment: No, migration is not a model, it is a file under `migrations` directory. Please, post `app1.0005_auto_20160217_1346` migration

Comment: edited..pls check..migration file included

Comment: I tried everything ..by giving arguments & all..But it simply giving me error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through the same problem some months back.I Just deleted the birthdate field changes in all the migration Files inside migration folder. Then I replaced the birthdate with this code:-

```
birthdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then after applying migration ,it works fine...

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have passed DateTimeField

```
birth_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

in your APP1Model(model) and migration shows DateFields

```
models.DateField(blank=True, default='', null=True)
```

first correct your Model and don't pass `default='' in DateField,`

**Use `DateField` instead of `DatiTimeField` for birthdate**

then remove your migration file app1.0005_auto_20160217_1346

and run **makemigrations** and **migrate** your app it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `DateField` to `DateTimeField` is not a bad idea. Although, there is a `DateField` and a `DateTimeField`, which are different for some reasons.

This error happens when a default value is applied to `DateField` in `models.py` in the wrong format.

According to your terminal output, the error occurs in migration file `0005_auto_20160217_1346.py`. You must find that migration file in 'app1/0005_auto_20160217_1346.py`, edit it and look for:

```
...

migrations.AddField(
    model_name='app1model',
    name='birth_date',
    field=models.DateField(blank=True, default='<jamming-date>', null=True),
),

...
```

Now, you can see the `DateField` with the `default` attribute containing a `<jamming-date>` with format `%d-%m-%Y`, for example. Django needs a `%Y-%m-%d` format.

In order to solve this problem, **delete** the `default` attribute, **save** the file and **make migrations** again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove default=' ' in migrations file and run migrate .

Before:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='formd',
    name='cash_payment_date',
    field=models.DateField(blank=True, default='', help_text='Date of Cash Payment', null=True),
),
```

After:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='formd',
    name='cash_payment_date',
    field=models.DateField(blank=True, help_text='Date of Cash Payment', null=True),
),
```

Removed default=''

Ran makemigrations

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error after trying to change the default property on a DateTime from blank '' (set in my initial migration file) to django.utils.timezone.now (in a later migration).  You need to go back and edit your 0001_Initial.py file and change the default value to whatever you want it to be now.  It seems like when applying migrations Django is referencing back to that initial file for validation and throwing the error, which can be a bit misleading, took me a few hours trying to sort out why... hopefully I save someone some time :)