# Django DateField gives validation errors

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models

This question is similar to [Resolving ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."] in Django 1.9.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473950/resolving-validationerror-u-value-has-an-invalid-date-format-it-must-be-in) but I can't see what to do. I'm using django 2.0.4 and they were using 1.9.2

I have the following models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Flight(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    dep_time = models.TimeField()
    dep_delay = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arr_time = models.TimeField()
    arr_delay = models.DurationField()
    cancelled = models.BooleanField()
    carrier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tailnum = models.IntegerField()
    flight = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    air_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    distance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.DurationField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.flight} {self.dest} {self.date}'
```

I'm trying to run this script from the django shell to update my database:

```
data = data.applymap(str)
data['month'] = data['month'].str.pad(2,side='left',fillchar='0')
data['day'] = data['day'].str.pad(2,side='left',fillchar='0')
data['date'] = data[['year', 'month', 'day']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
data['dep_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'].str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M',errors='coerce').dt.time
data['arr_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['arr_time'].str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M',errors='coerce').dt.time
data['duration'] = data[['hour', 'min']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
data['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(data['duration'].str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M',errors='coerce').dt.time
data['date'] = data[['month', 'day', 'year']].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x), axis=1)
data = data.drop(['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'min'], axis=1)
cols = ['date', 'dep_time', 'dep_delay', 'arr_time',
        'arr_delay', 'cancelled', 'carrier',
        'tailnum', 'flight', 'origin',
        'dest', 'air_time', 'distance', 'duration']
data = data.reindex(columns=cols)
print(data.tail())
#
def timeStrFormat(time):

    time = str(time)

    newTime = time[:-2] + ':' + time[-2:]

    return newTime

flights = [
    Flight(
        date = data.iloc[row].loc['date'],
        dep_time = data.iloc[row].loc['dep_time'],
        dep_delay = data.iloc[row].loc['dep_delay'],
        arr_time = data.iloc[row].loc['arr_time'],
        arr_delay = data.iloc[row].loc['arr_delay'],
        cancelled = data.iloc[row].loc['cancelled'],
        carrier = data.iloc[row].loc['carrier'],
        tailnum = data.iloc[row].loc['tailnum'],
        flight = data.iloc[row].loc['flight'],
        origin = data.iloc[row].loc['origin'],
        dest = data.iloc[row].loc['dest'],
        air_time = data.iloc[row].loc['air_time'],
        distance = data.iloc[row].loc['distance'],
        duration = data.iloc[row].loc['duration'],
    )
    for row, _ in enumerate(data)
]
for f in flights: f.save()
```

And I get the following stacktrace errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 56, in <module>
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1283, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1236, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1236, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1235, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1276, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1271, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1246, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'01/01/2014' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

My df looks like this:

```
              date  dep_time dep_delay  arr_time arr_delay cancelled carrier  \
103992  05/11/2014  10:13:00        -2  12:47:00       -13         0      B6   
103993  05/11/2014  19:29:00        -1  22:15:00       -24         0      B6   
103994  05/11/2014  11:17:00         5  13:55:00         9         0      B6   
103995  05/11/2014  07:36:00       -10  09:24:00       -18         0      B6   
103996  05/11/2014  13:40:00         0  16:47:00        10         0      B6
```

Do I need to force pandas to render the date in YYYY-MM-DD format? I don't see how to do that without converting it into a str and I want to put it into sqlite3 as a date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date in your DF to datetime object and then insert it into the models.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["05/11/2014", "05/11/2014"]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date
0  2014-05-11
1  2014-05-11
```

Comment: Will that put it into django as a str tho? And will django then be able to interpret it as a datetime?

Comment: In that case you can just use `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`

Comment: It still seems to be returning the 05/11/2014 format?

Comment: Hold on I have a line of code in there that adds '/' - my bad!