# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, datefield

I using Django version 2.0.7 and I tried to make a Date Module Field Until I faced this error :

```
Date = models.DateField(blank=True, default='', null=True, help_text='today date.')
```

I used this code before and it worked but now after `python manage.py makemigrations` that I use `python manage.py migrate` I faced to this error.
full logs:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Blog, Portfolio, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying Blog.0002_auto_20180728_0218...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 525, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 122, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 629, in _alter_field
    old_default = self.effective_default(old_field)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 240, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1276, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1271, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "D:\Learn\Projects\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1246, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

I even try to remove all migrations and db and make new migrationsbut it doesn't work too.
this link doesnt work for me too :
[Resolving ValidationError: [u“'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.”] in Django 1.9.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473950/resolving-validationerror-u-value-has-an-invalid-date-format-it-must-be-in)

**In Addision, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: The `default` can *not* be the empty string, since that is not a `Date`.

Comment: so if i use '1111-11-11' value for default, its gonna works?

Comment: now I try a string , a number and '1111-11-11' too, but still not working.

Comment: No, for example `date(1111, 11, 11)` (with `from datetime import date`).

Comment: if you mean this :
`Date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=date(1111, 11, 11), null=True, help_text="Today Date.")`
its not work too and i still faced to same errorr.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem Your solution is work , all I have to do was remove all migrations then remove all data from database and again do migrations.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default can not be the empty string, since that is not a Date.
for example use `date(1111, 11, 11)` with `from datetime import date` in modals page
then if you will be get same error , you have to **delete all migrations** and **erase your database data** too and **do migration**s again.

Comment: **for erase database data follow this:**
if you use sqllite the only thing that you have to do is that remove `.sqllite3`
**for migration use this command :**
`python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`
`python manage.py migrate <appname>`
and if migrate command not work, use this instead:
`python manage.py migrate --fake`

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

import pytz
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_date
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

default_app_config = 'patch.PatchConfig'


def patch():
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            if not value:
                value = None
            elif not parse_date(value):
                try:
                    value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value)).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
                except:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        self.error_messages['invalid'],
                        code='invalid',
                        params={'value': value},
                    )
        if not prepared:
            value = self.get_prep_value(value)
        return connection.ops.adapt_datetimefield_value(value)

    DateTimeField.get_db_prep_value = get_db_prep_value


class PatchConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'patch'

    def ready(self):
        patch()
```

You may be need this patch

Answer (score 0):

I have the same format error, when I was updateing my model.py

I show you my scenerio and maybe it will help. So I had an existing class and want to add this line:

```
time = models.TimeField()
```

than I did makemigrations and now the important part

```
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value
for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

choose 1) and type timezone.now for setting the default value --
migrate and you got it